# IF AND statement in EXCEL

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement

I want to remove the 0's from the cells without resorting to formatting

[image: picture of what I see now for the 0's]

And I want it to return something from a single analyst where the Pass/Fail column is Yes or Maybe
So IF("[analyst name]" is in that column AND the pass/fail column != "No")

[image: Picture of the Pass/Fail column]

This is the code I have at the moment with [ANALYST NAME] being the name of the employee I'm congregating data for

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Raw Data'!A1:AA1210,SMALL(IF("[ANALYST NAME]"='Raw Data'!B1:B1210,ROW('Raw Data'!A1:AA1210),""),ROW()-1),COLUMN('Raw Data'!A1:AA1210)), "")
```

This is what the Raw Data table looks like:

[image: Raw Data Table]

I'm working out of excel from windows 7

Comment: Sorry but are there 2 questions here you want answered?

Comment: Yes

I want the equation to return blanks instead of 0's and I want it to return the Yes and Maybe rows only

Comment: technically you should open 2 questions then. Also, with the large matrix where you want to remove the zeros, are they formulas or raw data?

Comment: Sorry this is my first post on stackoverflow. the Raw Data table is just data that I have input into the excel. It doesnt automatically show up like that.

Comment: ok, I ask the question because if that matrix is all formulas then you’d change the formula so it doesn’t show a zero. If they’re raw values then we can construct a macro that removes the 0’s automatically. So which is it? It sounds like they’re raw values, not formulas?

Comment: Alternatively, there’s an option in Excel to show cells with a 0 as blank, it’s not formatting as such, just an option. Would that do the job for you?

Comment: I've tried adding in the IF statement from this link (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/display-or-hide-zero-values-3ec7a433-46b8-4516-8085-a00e9e476b03) to remove 0's but I'm not sure where to place it in the formula. The formatting to remove 0's is easy and I can do a macro for that.

Comment: The bigger issue is trying to filter out the No's from the Pass/Fail column since I can't format the array as a table and do it from there, and even if I filter the Raw data tab to only show yes/maybe it still pulls the no's